# Save values of a foreach loop into a variable for further use

Tags: php, foreach

I have a foreach loop that echoes $content. In addition I would like to save the current value of content to a variable using $i. For example the first value of content to be saved in var1, the second in var2 and so on.

My purpose is to echo var1 or var2 where I want.

How can I do this ? Thank you!

```
$i=1;
foreach($txts as $txt) {
$content = $txt->nodeValue;
echo $content;
// SAVE CONTENT VALUE TO VAR1, VAR2, VAR3....
$i=$i+1;
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but this sorta feels like homework ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
${'var' . $i} = $content;
```

But you don't need to do this. Use arrays instead:

```
$values[$i] = $content;
```

And to echo them:

```
for ($j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++) {
    echo ${'var' . $j};
}
```

or with arrays:

```
foreach($values as $content) {
    echo $content;
}
```

Comment: just note that arrays start counting from 0.

Comment: Thank you! can I echo it outside of the loop ?

Comment: Of course you can, updated. But now the question looks indeed like homework. I'd recommend to read the manual